# What is the definition of a "binary" coproduct and "binary" coequalizer?

Tags: category-theory, definition

I came across this term in Mac Lane's Category theory and it hasn't been defined previously in the text.

It's quoted as:

> If a category has (binary) coproducts and coequalizers, prove that is also has pushouts.

Can someone define what a binary coproduct and binary coequalizer is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be parsed as "(binary coproducts) and (coequalisers)".
A binary coproduct is a coproduct of two objects.

Comment: By "has binary coproducts" and "has coequalizers", is he implying that for every pair $a,b$ in $C$ there's a coproduct and for every pair of parallel arrows there's a coequalizer?

Comment: @OliverG That's it. That also implies it has all finite colimits.

Answer (score 1):

A binary coproduct is a coproduct of two objects. Normally 'coequaliser' implies binary (i.e. a coequaliser of two parallel morphisms), but I suppose it's possible to have coequalisers of different arities.